# How to change mat-input label after focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change mat-input label after focus .
Any idea how to do it ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXZg.png)

Comment: For a next question, you should include some more informations, especially some code snippets or even a reproducable example =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the [mat-form-field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api) to a [Variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) and then reference the `focused` property.

```js
<mat-form-field #field>
  <mat-label *ngIf="field._control.focused">SECRET</mat-label>
  <mat-label *ngIf="!field._control.focused">Password</mat-label>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```